# Other flag raised from Triage suggesting options not available rejected

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, vote-to-close, triage

In the Triage review queue, I came to [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399800/fetch-descending-order-but-display-as-ascending-in-mysql) which seemed to be of very low quality. As the Very Low Quality flag was not available, I raised an Other flag. It was subsequently declined with:

> declined - Please use standard close votes or close flags for this
>   instead of flagging for moderators.

There is no downvote or close button available in the triage queue. However, I was not sure whether to raise this to a moderator but somehow it didn't feel right to leave the question as it is.
Is there any better way to approach these kinds of questions/reviews?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is no downvote, close available in triage review.

You're right that there is no downvote or low-quality flag option in Triage.

There are close options though. So if you see a question that should be closed, click ***Unsalvageable*** , then ***it should be closed for another reason...*** , and select your normal close reason from there.

[image]

So it appears that your other flag for moderator attention was declined because you should've just voted to close the question instead of alerting a moderator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i am aware of that section but the options available inside that again were not exactly the reason why this should be closed. I agree raising this to moderator was not best option/right. May be i should skip these kind of questions and leave it to it's fate...

Comment: @Aditya at no point was that question low quality. Unclear what you're asking, not providing all the necessary info, etc, probably. Low quality flags on questions should only be used when the question is like a bunch of random letters like "jakfsdoadioaj fjdoasfjdaodfj" , or even in a different language than english. So it is seldomly used compared to closing.